# loading seed data for a rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have an existing database in which I am converting a formerly 'NULL' column to one that has a default value (and populating that with said default value). However, that value is an ID of a record I need to create. If I put this record in `db/seeds.rb`, it won't run because `db/seeds.rb` runs after migrations -- but the migration needs seed data. If I leave the record creation in the migration, then I don't get the record if I make a fresh database with `db:load`. Is there a better way other than duplicating this in both `db/seeds.rb` and the migration?

Thanks!

Comment: will you please post your migration?

Comment: Interesting question. I am surprised that Rails doesn't provide a standard way for this.

Comment: @Brett - Think for example of dropdowns that take their data from the DB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you should treat this in both `db/seeds.rb` and the migration.

The migration is used to get an existing database from an older version to another version while `seeds.rb` and `schema.rb` are used for a fresh database with the latest version.

Comment: You can always make a migration run the 'rake db:seed' rake task. :)

Comment: Which might suck on a production db that already exists since a few years... ;)

Answer (score 12):

While I can understand your desire to stay DRY and not have to write this in both the migration and  seeds.rb, I think you should write it in both places. Not just to make it work, but to accomplish different requirements related to your problem.

1. You need to ensure that your migration can execute properly regardless of external processes. That means you should put any code required within that specific migration. This isn't to accomplish anything besides making sure your migration executes properly. Suppose someone else tries to migrate without knowing you put part of the code in seeds.rb, it would be very difficult for them to figure out what's going on.
2. You can make db:load work properly by including similar code in seeds.rb. However, you should be evaluating the current state of your database in seeds.rb due to the fact that it runs after the migrations. So you can check to see if the column exists, and what the default value is etc. This means that if the migration ran and took care of everything, seeds.rb doesn't repeat work or modify values inappropriately. However, if the migration did not set these variables as expected, it is able to set the values.

I'd recommend looking at it as two separate issues so you can be more confident of each one executing successfully independent of one another. It also creates better maintainability for understanding by yourself or others of what's happening in the future.